# FacebookApiException Unknown identifier when getting user's feed (me/home)

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In my Facebook app I am seeing an error from the Facebook SDK for some users when getting their feed (using `me/home?limit=1000&fields=from.fields(id,name),likes.fields(id),comments.fields(from.fields(id))`).

The error is:

```
Facebook.FacebookApiException: (Exception - #0) Unknown identifier, 0_xxxxxxx
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
```

(Where `0_xxxxxxx` is different for each user)

I've had a look through the SDK source code and can't see what would be generating this error.

Any thoughts about what might be causing this?

Comment: Might want to keep an eye on [this bug too](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/101139556726683?browse=search_50e0be62e8de83743025797)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate this error through the Graph API explorer. It is not an issue with the C# SDK.

This seems to happen for posts with a specific limited privacy setting. For example someone else's post in your stream. This post will be affected by both privacy settings of the users involved.

Making some assumptions, the actual "identifier" that is causing the problem seems to be in the format of

```
user-id_object-id
```

The `user_id` can not be determined hence the `0` and the post is now tied to the privacy of an undetermined user.

<s>Sorry to go on like this without actually providing a solution... Just sharing my investigations...</s>

For the moment, the workaround would be to eliminate your use of field expansion. I was unable to get the same error once I took it out.

```
me/home?fields=from,likes,comments&limit=1000
```

It means you'll have to do some extra parsing... But don't remove your old code, just comment it out to be ready for when the field expansion bug is sorted out.

Comment: Thanks for the info Lix, good to know that it's not an issue with the C# SDK. Now I'm wondering if there's a workaround for it.

Comment: I've implemented your suggested workaround, it works well. Thanks again.